# Как удалять слова из массива?

Tags: c

Нужно удалить слова из массива в интервале который ввёл пользователь.
Например с 3 до 6 слова.

Вот что я понаписал,но у меня выдаёт ошибку "invalid operands to binary - (have 'int' and 'int (*)(const char *)')" там где "for (i = 0; i < w - remove+1; i++)"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define b 13
#define w 8        

int a,j,i,index,remoe;
char e;



char *virk[b] = {"zilonis", "suns",
 "alnis", "zakis", "begemots",
 "lapsa", "dzeguze", "skudra", "vilks",
 "zirafs", "varna", "kakis","stirna"};



char *uzd[w];
char *arr[w];



void izvade(char *x){   
  printf("%8s\t",x); }           



void dzesana(char random[w])  {
printf("No kura varda nodzest: ");
    scanf("%s", &index);



    printf("Cik nodzest:");
    scanf("%s", &remoe);


  for (i = 0; i < index-1; i++)
    random[w]= arr[i];
    for (j = index + remove - 1; j<w,j++,i++;)  
    {
    random[w] = arr[j];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < w - remove+1; i++)
    printf("%s ", random[w]);
}


main(){


for (a=0;a<b;a++)                                                                                  
    izvade(*(virk+a));


cikls:

printf("\n");
printf("Tiek izvadits masivs ar nejausiem vardiem!");
printf("\n\n");



printf("\n");
getch();
printf("\nVardi tiks nodzesti");
printf("\n\n");



dzesana();

izeja:
printf("\n\n");
printf("Vai Jus velaties atkartot?");
printf("\n");
printf("Ja(j) vai Ne(n)!");
scanf("%s", &e);
if (e=='j')goto cikls;
else if (e=='n') exit(0);
else goto izeja;
getch();
}
```

Comment: Покажите Ваши попытки решить задачу, т.е. код.

Comment: @AidenKothen Покажите, что уже сделано, иначе не ровен час Ваш вопрос будет удален. Отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: 1) Как минимум, ошибка вот тут: `random[w] = arr[i]`, т.к. объявлено `char *arr[w]` но `char random[w]`. 2) `remoe` и `remove` - опечатка? 3) Старайтесь для названия функций использовать английский, понимающих литовский(?) тут немного.

Comment: В коде множество ошибок несоответствия типов. Помимо уже озвученных, ещё и в `scanf`. При чтении целого указывается формат строки `%s`, должен быть `%d`. Присутствуют и другие ошибки. Сложно искать ошибку в коде, который почти полностью является ошибкой.

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас слова - элементы массива, то самый простой вариант это пересоздать массив и записать туда все не удаленные слова. Если у Вас массив типа char, то аналогично, только считать длины слов и записывать уже исходя из этого